# What is HaAshmurah HaRishona in the Mishnah

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, midrash, mishna, chasidut-hasidism

BH

What is HaAshmura HaRishonah?

Someone told me it is just a division in the night while someone else told me that it is referring to the Leviim guarding in the temple which ever it is does it speak more about them in the Mishna and what are they?[image]

Comment: Leviim did have nightly watches, but that's a separate thing in Mishna Tamid and Middot. Shmuel's answer is what this is referring to

Answer (score 4):

Refer to the [Bartenura](https://www.sefaria.org/Bartenura_on_Mishnah_Berakhot.1.1.2) on that Mishnah:

> עד סוף האשמורה הראשונה – The first third of the night (is the end of the first “watch”), as the night is divided into three watches, and from then onwards is no longer called the time [for the] Recitation of the Shema (Deuteronomy 6:4-9; 11:13-21; Numbers 15:37-41) when lying down, and we do not refer to it as “when you lie down” (Deuteronomy 6:7), and prior to the stars coming out (literally, “going out”), it is also considered daytime and not the time of lying down. And those who recite Evening Shema early while it is still day, rely upon that [opinion] of Rabbi Yehuda who said further on in Chapter “Tefillat HaShahar”/The Morning Prayer/Amidah (Chapter 4 of Berakhot, Mishnah 1), that the Afternoon prayer is recited until “Plag HaMinhah”/the middle of the afternoon (the half-way point between the time when the Tamid/Daily Sacrifice was offered – 3:30 pm and 6:00 pm when the time of sunset arrives at the Vernal and Autumnal Equinoxes), which is an hour and a quarter prior to the night time. And we establish (literally, “hold”), that he followed [the opinion of] Rabbi Yehudah, and immediately when the time for Minhah ends, the time for the Evening Recitation of the Shema begins.

See also Yoma 20a, where it says it is at the end of the first watch. See also the Rambam on the first Mishnah of Berachos.